# How to get the image size (width and height)?

Tags: image, groovy, javax.imageio

I am new to grails. I spent fare amount of time in search of finding the image size using grails but end up with nothing.
I want to find the image size (width and height) using grails by just giving path of the image. Is it possible using grails? if yes, how?
Please suggest me easy way to find the image size.

Thanks in advance,
Venkatesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing you have an image in C:\tmp, this would do it:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
...

def img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\tmp\\cherry.jpg"));
println("Width:"+img.getWidth()+" Height:"+img.getHeight());
```

ImageIO also supports reading from a URL: [see ImageIO javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for the reply. will try this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer of @Nicolas Modrzyk I have been able to write a one liner for the bash.

`java -jar groovy-all.jar -e 'javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File(args[0])).with { println "width: $width, height: $height" }' -- fancyImage.jpg`